# Python sockets - multiple clients to one server, bad connection or bad threading?

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a p2p chat in python. The idea is for a client to be able to become the server if it goes down. This is for learning purposes, so I'm just doing this local on my laptop.

But as of now I'm struggling with just communicating between client-server.

I have a terminal window open for the server. 
2 terminal windows for clients.

If I connect both clients, both can send messages to the server and the server broadcasts the messages to all clients.
But after 1 message from the second client, only one client can send messages but the server prints out port from both clients.

Example output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUiZE.png

I have googled like crazy. 
I have tried putting the socket creation inside the while loop (see code below).

```py
class Server:
    connections = []

    def __init__(self):
        print("server created")

        # I have tried putting this part in the while loop below
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        host = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        port = 5001
        sock.bind((host, port))
        print("Hosting server on " + host + ":" + str(port) + " hostname: " + hostname)

        sock.listen(1)  # I have tried changing the value from 1 to 2, 5, 10 etc but no difference

        while True:
            connection, client_address = sock.accept()
            print(str(client_address) + " connected!")

            # create new thread
            listener_thread = Thread(target=self.server_listener, args=(connection, client_address))
            listener_thread.daemon = True
            listener_thread.start()

            self.connections.append(connection)


    def server_listener(self, connection, client_address):
        while True:
            chunk = connection.recv(1024)
            if not chunk:
                print(str(client_address) + " disconnected")
                break
            elif chunk[0:3] == b'msg':
                # Send out message to other clients connected
                for connection in self.connections:
                    connection.send(chunk[3:].decode())

            print(str(client_address) + ':' + chunk[3:])
```

My client class is basically the same, but with connect instead of bind. Client also has a threading method which listens for server messages.

I'm not getting any error messages, so I don't even know if there's anything wrong with threading or network part.

I expected that the server should be able to have multiple threads and being able to have multiple clients connected and for them to be able to communicate.

Comment: use try expect around your code blocks and print any exceptions. That will help a lot.

Comment: I have tried putting it around every communication code, and no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding connection in

```
    def server_listener(self, connection, client_address):
        ...
            elif chunk[0:3] == b'msg':
                # Send out message to other clients connected
                for connection in self.connections: << HERE 
                    connection.send(chunk[3:].decode())
```

Change the connection in self.connections to c in self.connections and try.